# поменять текст кнопки из View (Present Modally) в предыдущем View

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Есть обычная кнопка при клике на которую открывается вьюшка с помощью Present Modally, там парсится JSON и при клике на строку возвращается инфа обратно в предыдущий ViewController и отображается в ViewDidLoad()

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GeneralChooser") as! GeneralChooser
    controller.idSet = idAr[indexPath.row]
    controller.nameSet = nameAr[indexPath.row]
    dismiss(animated: true)
    present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

странно, что в print инфа отображается, но вот поставить её в название кнопки не могу

```
rimB.setTitle(idSet, for: .normal)
```

Насколько я понимаю, вью элементы прорисовываются по своему и это все делло нужно рефрешнуть, или как. Спасибо)

Comment: А как информация возвращается обратно? Какой источник данных?
Если контроллер уже был загружен то нужно обновлять вьюхи в viewWillAppear()

Comment: вот, как в теле вопроса. 
controller.idSet = idAr[indexPath.row]
controller.nameSet = nameAr[indexPath.row],   строки взятые из tableview при клике передаются в GeneralChooser

Comment: Где Вы вызываете rimB.setTitle(idSet, for: .normal)? И это не в предыдущем Вы меняете, а создаете новый.

Comment: Значит я не до конца понимаю методологию) rimB.setTitle(idSet, for: .normal) я меняю в viewDidLoad(), но также пробовал в viewWillAppear()

Comment: Действительно не понятно что где вызывается, но если print() выводит информацию, то вызывайте setTitle в главном потоке DispatchQueue.main.async { //... }